# Android POST JSON to server inconsistencies

Tags: php, android, json

My code posts a json object to a server. This is my PHP

```
<?php
$jsonString = file_get_contents('php://input');
$jsonObj = json_decode($jsonString, true);

if( !empty($jsonObj)) { 
        $players = $jsonObj['Players'];
        $details = $jsonObj['Details'];
        $events  = $jsonObj['Events'];
        print "YES";
        var_dump($players);
}else{
print "NO";
}
 ?>
```

Here is a snippet of the android code.

```
inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

        String status = httpResponse.getStatusLine().toString();
        if (!status.equals("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error")){
            if(inputStream != null){
                result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);   
            }
            else{
                result = "Did not work!";
            }
        }else{
            System.out.println("500 Error");

        }



    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    System.out.println(result);
    return result;
```

The problem I am having is that when i run this code 'NO' is output on the PHP page but the response I get from server (result) shows 'YES' and outputs JSON.

- Can anyone explain this?
  [image]

[image]

Comment: $jsonObj is empty and you get 'NO' when you run code via browser (you dont pass any json). It seems you pass some json via android request. What's the problem?

Comment: yes so when i pass the data to server (click button) via android and refresh page should the output in browser not be YES?

Comment: Can you show the snippet how you pass data from android to server?

Comment: If you want to pass data from andorid to server, your code is right. You need preserve this data on a server if you want to show it in browser

Comment: When you open url in a browser, you do new request to server.

Comment: @rNix, you should provide an answer so that the OP can mark this question as answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered in comments, but @Tanis.7x said I should add an answer.

`$jsonObj` is empty and you get 'NO' when you run code via browser (you don't pass any json). It seems you pass some json via android request.

You need preserve json data on a server if you want to show it in a browser.

```
$jsonString = file_get_contents('php://input');
$jsonObj = json_decode($jsonString, true);

$file = 'tmp';

if(!empty($jsonObj)) { 
    file_put_contents($file, $jsonString);
} else {
    $content = file_get_contents($file);
    if ($content) {
        echo $content;
        //$jsonObj = json_decode($content, true);
    } else {
        echo 'NO';
    }
}
```